# popup angular4 não funciona?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, popup

Galera, estou com um problema no angular 4. Estou tentando usar o componente `ng2-opd-popup`. Ele instala certo, mas quando eu declaro ele no `app.modules.ts` ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function, resolving symbol NgModule in
>   C:/Mercurial/catalogonew/Project/Liera.Catalogo/Liera.Catalogo.UI.Angular2/node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   C:/Mercurial/catalogonew/Project/Liera.Catalogo/Liera.Catalogo.UI.Angular2/node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   C:/Mercurial/catalogonew/Project/Liera.Catalogo/Liera.Catalogo.UI.Angular2/node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules/@angular/core/src/core.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol NgModule in
>   C:/Mercurial/catalogonew/Project/Liera.Catalogo/Liera.Catalogo.UI.Angular2/node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol PopupModule in
>   C:/Mercurial/catalogonew/Project/Liera.Catalogo/Liera.Catalogo.UI.Angular2/node_modules/ng2-opd-popup/components/popup/popup.module.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol PopupModule in
>   C:/Mercurial/catalogonew/Project/Liera.Catalogo/Liera.Catalogo.UI.Angular2/modules/ng2-opd-popup/components/popup/popup.module.d.ts

No `App.Module` estou implementando ele da seguinte forma:

```
import {PopupModule} from 'ng2-opd-popup';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'detalhe/:id', component: DetalheComponent },  
  { path: 'busca/:sku', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'buscarefresh/:sku', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'buscacarro/:carro', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'autocadastro/:chave', component: CadastroComponent },  
  { path: 'carrinho', component: CarrinhoComponent },
  { path: 'pedido',component: PedidoComponent },
  { path: 'liberar-cadastro',component: LiberarCadastroComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    BarComponent,
    DetalheComponent,
    CarrinhoComponent,
    PedidoComponent,
    CadastroComponent,
    LiberarCadastroComponent,
    AuthDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes
    ),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    SelectModule,
    PopupModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [ 
    BaseAddressService,
    HttpClientService,
    TokenService,
    AuthService,
    ItemService,
    FiltroService
  ],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Como posso resolver esse problema? Já olhei o arquivo que supostamente estaria errado mas não achei nada que o Angular talvez reclamaria.

Comment: Gabriel, sou novo no Angular4 (estou fazendo um curso agora) e estou usando o VS Code, que importa de forma automática os módulos necessários. Porém, está importando desta forma "@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module", causando erro já na compilação. Quando altero para "@angular/core" a compilação é finalizada com sucesso; verifique se não é esta a causa do seu problema.